# How to get username to appear on label when user logs in

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a website using asp.net and vb on visual studio 2013. I have a log in that holds a session - When the user logs in and are authenticated they are redirected to the user page (user.aspx). This is the patient table (this is dummy data):

[image: Patientid]

The login:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Pages_Login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click

    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim bAuthethicated As Boolean
    username = txtuser.Text
    password = txtpassword.Text
    bAuthethicated = CheckUser(username, password)

    If bAuthethicated Then
        Response.Redirect("user.aspx", True)
    Else
        lblresult.Text() = "Incorrect Student Number and/or Password"
    End If

End Sub
```

The session:

```
Public Function CheckUser(username As String, password As String) As Integer
    Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT * FROM Patient  Where Username=@USERNAME AND Password=@PASSWORD"
    Dim found = 0
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Laura\Final_proj\App_Data\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")

        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = username
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = password
        conn.Open()

        Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
            found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
        End While

        reader.Close()
    End Using
    Return (found)
End Function
```

Once logged in the user is redirected to the user page and the label displays the PatientId:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Label1.Text = Session("PatientId")
End Sub
```

I want this label to display the username from the table instead of Patient id - it works when I PatientId is entered but when I changed it to username but it does not display anything anymore does the session then have to be changed to username or can I still hold the session under patientId and display their username? - I will have like a welcome note infront of the label but I dont want the patient to log in and see their ID I want them to see their username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just retrieve the username from the database as well. reader.Item() can be used to reference any of the columns returned by your query:

```
While reader.Read()
    Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
    Session("PatientUsername") = CStr(reader.Item("Username"))
    found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
End While`
```

...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Label1.Text = Session("PatientUsername")
End Sub`
```

Comment: from the database it is username - do I have to name it something different "patientUsername" ?

Comment: Glad it works. in reference to your comment above, in the Session you can call it whatever you want. You could write `Session("Fishcakes") = CStr(reader.Item("Username"))`  There doesn't have to be any relationship between them, you're just assigning a value from one variable to another. But obviously it's better to use meaningful names so that it's easier to understand what the code means when you come back to it later. Equally you could use the same name - `Session("Username") = CStr(reader.Item("Username"))`. That would work fine because Session and reader are two separate contexts

Comment: Great ADyson! this is very helpful - thanks for the help to my learning!

Comment: ADyson could you help with this question? :)  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764919/display-a-table-on-a-webpage-from-database

Answer (score 1):

Yes i believe you can still hold the session under userID but display the username. You are not adding the username to the session. You have to add it the same way you added the userID.

```
Session("username") = CInt(reader.Item("Username"));
```

Then to display you can use a simple:

```
Welcome <%Response.Write(Session("username"))%>
```

You may have to modify the code a bit to fit your needs, but something similar should make it work.